# Function with dates

Tags: python, dataframe, date

I created a function with the objective that converts the value of Colombian pesos to dollars depending on the date of the index in a dataframe:

```
def pesosdolar(fecha):
  fecha=pd.to_datetime(fecha)
  plus_one_day = fecha + timedelta(days=1)
  minus_one_day= fecha - timedelta(days=1)
  try: 
    copusd = yf.Ticker("USDCOP=X").history(start=fecha, end=fecha)
    return copusd['Close'].iloc[0]
  except IndexError:
    alt = yf.Ticker("USDCOP=X").history(start=fecha - timedelta(days=3), end=fecha - timedelta(days=1))
    return alt['Close'].mean()
```

when I write a simple date ('2022-04-28' for example) it works perfect, the problem is when I try to put the dataframe

```
pesosdolar(df_ordenes['createdAt'])
```

The warning:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Further, this does not work:

```
df_ordenes = df_ordenes.assign(dolar = lambda x: (x['amount_in'] / pesosdolar(x['createdAt'])))
```

Comment: You are passing a whole series by `df_ordenes['createdAt']` instead of single date. 
Check your output by `print(df_ordenes['createdAt'])`.
Also please show what is your dataframe `df_ordenes` and what do you want exactly from it, so that we can answer better.

Comment: Yes, I got to because i have to take a lambda function on the order value column and divide the createdAt column
'df_ordenes = df_ordenes.assign(dolar = lambda x: (x['amount_in'] / pesosdolar(x['createdAt'])))'

Comment: I did not understand what you meant, perhaps paste the code that you are trying.

Comment: that function will throw me a value, I have to take that value and operate it on the dataframe to obtain the number I want in each one of the rows of the dataframe

Comment: `df_ordenes = df_ordenes.assign(dolar = lambda x: (x['amount_in'] / pesosdolar(x['createdAt'])))`